# Can we use user defined anchor for computed-bucket in range constraints?

Tags: anchor, marklogic, facet

I have some document content like this, and I have a range index on element "key".

```
<root>
  <key>NAM</key>
  <key>NA</key>
  <key>North America</key>
</root>
```

When generating facets, I want to calculate the "NAM" and "NA" into one group instead each one of them.

So I tried to use the computed-bucket, more or less like this example:

```
<constraint name="date">
  <range type="xs:dateTime" facet="true">
    <element ns="http://example.com" name="entry"/> 
    <attribute ns="" name="date"/>

    <computed-bucket lt="-P1Y" anchor="start-of-year" name="older">Older</computed-bucket>
    <computed-bucket lt="P1Y" ge="P0Y" anchor="start-of-year" name="year">This Year</computed-bucket>
    <computed-bucket lt="P1M" ge="P0M" anchor="start-of-month" name="month">This Month</computed-bucket>
    <computed-bucket lt="P1D" ge="P0D" anchor="start-of-day" name="today">Today</computed-bucket>
    <computed-bucket ge="P0D" anchor="now" name="future">Future</computed-bucket>

    <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
  </range>
</constraint>
```

But I noticed that the anchor is generally pre-defined by MarkLogic, so I am asking: can I use my own defined **anchor**, like a function below?

```
<computed-bucket ge="P0D" anchor="myAnchor.xqy" name="future">Future</computed-bucket>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you would like to do? Your xml snippet doesn't contain dates, so what should myAnchor.xqy do?

Comment: The myAnchor.xqy is to define my own grouping strategy, like put the "Asia" and "NAM" into one facet group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computed buckets are not an option for string values. And if buckets are too rigid, consider writing a custom facet. Here is an example of one that allows grouping value patterns:

https://github.com/grtjn/ml-constraints/blob/master/grouping-constraint.xqy

HTH!

Comment: My collaborator implement it by custom facet.

Answer (score 4):

You can use bucket instead of computed-bucket for a range that you define:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_80046

which would be something like:

```
<bucket name="N" lt="O" ge="N">Terms that start with N</bucket>
```

Hoping that helps,

Comment: This way can be somewhat hard coding. what if someday i want to put "Asia" and "NAM" into one facets group? The reason I choose to use the computed-bucket is to accomplish more flexibility.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the concern.  You can change the buckets at any time.